# Add Parameters Function with OLEDB data using String Array

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, parameters, oledb

I am quite new to VB.NET programming so forgive my ignorance. I am trying to update data from an excel spreadsheet to a SQL database by using OLEDB to get the excel information and then passing the OLEDB info to parameters for a SQLCommand update. The For statement area seems to be the problem as I keep getting the error below. I added some messageboxes to see if I was getting data in **paraArray(i)** and **excelArray(i)** and it worked and looped perfectly. Just do not know why it is saying I have not declared the variable when I execute the sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar

**ERROR:**
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll. Additional information: **Must declare the scalar variable "@INGREDIENTS"**.

If you need clarification I will provide. This is my first post on stackoverflow. I am excited to hear the experts.

```
sqlUpdate = "UPDATE xxxxx.dbo.testtable SET INGREDIENTS= @INGREDIENTS, SERVINGSIZE= @SERVINGSIZE where SPC= @SPC"

Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection("Server=Myserver;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=xx;Password=xxxxx")
            sqlCon.Open()

Dim excelCmd2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]", con)
Dim sqlQuery As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM xxxxx.dbo.testtable", sqlCon)

Using dataRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = excelCmd2.ExecuteReader()
                    If dataRead.HasRows() Then
                        While dataRead.Read()

                            Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
                            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
                            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlUpdate

                            Dim paraArray() As String = {"@SPC","@INGREDIENTS","@SERVINGSIZE"} 
                            Dim excelArray() As String = {"SPC", "INGREDIENTS", "SERVINGSIZE"}
                            Dim i As Integer = 0

                            For i = 0 To 2                                    
                                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraArray(i), SqlDbType.Variant).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item(excelArray(i)))
                                sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
                            Next

                        End While        
                    End If
                End Using
```

New Code after the correct answer by Bjorn and detail explanation by Steve.

```
sqlUpdate = "UPDATE xxxxx.dbo.testtable SET INGREDIENTS= @INGREDIENTS, SERVINGSIZE= @SERVINGSIZE where SPC= @SPC"

    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection("Server=Myserver;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=xx;Password=xxxxx")
                sqlCon.Open()

    Dim excelCmd2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]", con)
    Dim sqlQuery As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM xxxxx.dbo.testtable", sqlCon)
Dim paraArray() As String = {"@SPC", "@INGREDIENTS", "@SERVINGSIZE", "@SERV_IN_GRAMS", "@SERV_PER_CON", "@CALORIES", "@CALORIES_FAT", "@TOTAL_FAT", "@SAT_FAT", "@TRANS_FAT", "@POLY_FAT", "@MONO_FAT", "@CHOLESTEROL", "@POTASSIUM", "@SODIUM", "@TOTAL_CARB", "@DIET_FIBER", "@SUGARS", "@SUGAR_ALC", "@PROTEIN", "@VIT_A", "@VIT_C", "@CAL", "@IRON", "@VIT_D", "@VIT_E", "@VIT_K", "@THIAMIN", "@ROBO", "@NIACIN", "@VIT_B12", "@BIOTIN", "@PANTO_ACID", "@PHOSPHORUS", "@IODINE", "@MAGNESIUM", "@ZINC", "@SELENIUM", "@COPPER", "@MANGANESE", "@CHROMIUM", "@MOLYBDENUM", "@FOLATE", "@VIT_B6", "@CHLORIDE", "@PH", "@WATER_CONTENT", "@MOISTURE", "@FAT_PERCENT", "@ASH", "@SULFUR_DIOXIDE", "@PEROXIDE", "@SORBIC_ACID", "@TOTAL_PLATE", "@YEAST_MOLD", "@ENTER_BACT", "@COLIFORM", "@ECOLI", "@SALMONELLA", "@STAPH_AUR", "@LISTEROA", "@KOSHER", "@HALAL", "@ORGANIC", "@ALL_NAT", "@VEGETAR", "@VEGAN", "@RAW", "@SPROUTED", "@GLUTEN", "@WHEAT", "@CASEIN", "@CORN", "@DAIRY", "@EGG", "@GMO", "@LACTOSE", "@PEANUT", "@TREE_NUT", "@SOY", "@YEAST", "@SHELL_FISH", "@FISH", "@RECYCLE", "@BEEF_GRADE", "@CHILD_NUT", "@MARINE_CERT"}
            Using dataRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = excelCmd2.ExecuteReader()
                If dataRead.HasRows() Then

                    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
                    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlUpdate
                    For i = 0 To paraArray.Length - 1
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraArray(i), String.Empty)
                    Next
                    Dim excelArray() As String = {"SPC", "INGREDIENTS", "SERVINGSIZE", "SERV_IN_GRAMS", "SERV_PER_CON", "CALORIES", "CALORIES_FAT", "TOTAL_FAT", "SAT_FAT", "TRANS_FAT", "POLY_FAT", "MONO_FAT", "CHOLESTEROL", "POTASSIUM", "SODIUM", "TOTAL_CARB", "DIET_FIBER", "SUGARS", "SUGAR_ALC", "PROTEIN", "VIT_A", "VIT_C", "CAL", "IRON", "VIT_D", "VIT_E", "VIT_K", "THIAMIN", "ROBO", "NIACIN", "VIT_B12", "BIOTIN", "PANTO_ACID", "PHOSPHORUS", "IODINE", "MAGNESIUM", "ZINC", "SELENIUM", "COPPER", "MANGANESE", "CHROMIUM", "MOLYBDENUM", "FOLATE", "VIT_B6", "CHLORIDE", "PH", "WATER_CONTENT", "MOISTURE", "FAT_PERCENT", "ASH", "SULFUR_DIOXIDE", "PEROXIDE", "SORBIC_ACID", "TOTAL_PLATE", "YEAST_MOLD", "ENTER_BACT", "COLIFORM", "ECOLI", "SALMONELLA", "STAPH_AUR", "LISTEROA", "KOSHER", "HALAL", "ORGANIC", "ALL_NAT", "VEGETAR", "VEGAN", "RAW", "SPROUTED", "GLUTEN", "WHEAT", "CASEIN", "CORN", "DAIRY", "EGG", "GMO", "LACTOSE", "PEANUT", "TREE_NUT", "SOY", "YEAST", "SHELL_FISH", "FISH", "RECYCLE", "BEEF_GRADE", "CHILD_NUT", "MARINE_CERT"}
                    While dataRead.Read()
                        For i = 0 To excelArray.Length - 1

                            sqlCmd.Parameters(i).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item(excelArray(i)))
                        Next
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End While

                End If
            End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the ExecuteScalar outside the loop

```
For i = 0 To 2                                    
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraArray(i), SqlDbType.Variant).Value = _
           Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item(excelArray(i)))
Next
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In your code the command is executed too early. You have added only the first parameter and so you get the error. (By the way, that is not the correct syntax for [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which requires the parameter name and, as second parameter, the value to be used)

Not related to you problem, but [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used to retrieve a value (the first column of the first row) from an SELECT query. It works also for other kind of queries but the recommended method for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE is [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that returns the number of rows involved by your command

I also suggest a small optimization to your code. Move the creation of the SqlCommand outside the loop on the DataReader and inside the loop update only the values without recreating the command and the parameter collection

```
 Dim paraArray() As String = {"@SPC","@INGREDIENTS","@SERVINGSIZE"} 
 Using dataRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = excelCmd2.ExecuteReader()
    If dataRead.HasRows() Then
        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlUpdate
        For i = 0 To paraArray.Length - 1                                    
            sqlCmd.Parameters-AddWithValue(paraArray(i), string.Empty)
        Next

        Dim excelArray() As String = {"SPC", "INGREDIENTS", "SERVINGSIZE"}
        While dataRead.Read()
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For i = 0 To excelArray.Lenth - 1
                sqlCmd.Parameters(i).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item(excelArray(i)))
            Next
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End While        
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: I really like this idea to optimize the program, however in reality I am dealing with over 100+ parameters that I need to add and it seems cumbersome to list them under sqlCmd like this: sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPC"",string.Empty). I could be absolutely wrong. What do you think? Already my excelArray & paraArray are enormous, and it seems there should be an easier way to deal with this many parameters I am using. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, you could use a loop. If you really have over 100+ parameters then the optimization could be not so small after all. I will update the answer using a loop.

Comment: This worked like a charm! The ExecuteNonQuery information was very enlightening and I used that in my code as well as your optimization suggestions. Overall, learned a lot from you bud and am giving you the green check of approval. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the command before all parameters are set:

```vb
For i = 0 To 2                                    
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraArray(i), SqlDbType.Variant).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item(excelArray(i)))
    'Executes in first cycle and fails:
    sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
Next
```

So just move the `sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()` outside the loop:

```vb
For i = 0 To 2                                    
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraArray(i), SqlDbType.Variant).Value = Convert.ToString(dataRead.Item(excelArray(i)))
Next

sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
```